# Use of the p-norms in physical world (soft quest.)

Tags: soft-question, normed-spaces

Why is the $2$-norm $\lVert \rVert_2$ the only norm that correspond to our reality space? Are there any application in our physical universe of the $p$-norms (with $p\in \mathbb N^* \setminus \{2\} $) ?

Edit: I may have a hint on the use of other norms. When we travel through space at very long distances the trajectory we make is not a line, instead it *could* be useful to use a different norm to describe the trajectory.

Comment: The $l_{\infty}$ norm is the maximum; the $l_0$ norm is the number of non-zero elements of the vector.

Comment: Yup I forgot to include the $\infty$-norm in my question! Sorry

Comment: I don't think the $0$-"norm" such as you defined is a norm: it is not homogeneous

Comment: I think this is actually a very deep question and I'm not convinced I've ever seen a satisfying answer to it. Certainly I don't consider the current accepted answer to be satisfying.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan One much more interesting factoid IMO relating to distances and vector spaces is that only in 1D or 3D can a radial symmetric wave propagate distortionless. See http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~deleenhp/teaching/spring08/MAP4341/morley.pdf where implicitly they use the $l_2$ norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimension vector space, this is the only norm that is invariant under a rotation. Other norms will not preserve lengths.

As an example, if you have for example a unitary vector $(1,0,0,0,...)$ and it gets rotated, the only norm that will preserve its length is the 2-norm. So if a postulate is that there is no "preferred direction" in the "reality space" then this is the consequence.

You can define other norms, usually through a scalar product. There are some anisotropic norms that can have uses, especially within a medium that has some organization (e.g.: a crystal).

Comment: Well, hold on. "Other norms will not preserve lengths" is only true if you say that length is the $\ell_2$ norm. But if we decide we want to use the $\ell_p$ norm we should use that norm to define lengths! The real point here is that the $\ell_p$ norms don't admit continuous *linear* symmetries at all unless $p = 2$. So they can't possibly be consistent with the continuous symmetries (rotations, etc.) we see in nature.

Comment: Yes, we can't find a linear map that will preserve the norm of all vectors in a vector space for $p\ne2$. I just wanted to keep the explanation simple and intuitive.